ntoskrnl.exe BSOD, How to fix?
Got a new motherboard recently and the PC now just randomly crashes, the BSOD stop code:
driver_power_state_faliure

After looking in A BSOD Viewer it showed the Executable
ntokrnl.exe

The DRAM light on the motherboard is solid red all the time. I tried re-seating the RAM, CPU and the GPU and even only using 1 stick of RAM and integrated graphics, nothing. Also tried installing Windows again on a fresh SSD thinking it may of been interfering software or bad drivers but after a day it started crashing again.
The PC’s motherboard previously was
MAG B650 TOMAHAWK WIFI
MS-7D75 ver1.1

And Switched To a
Gigabyte Aorus x670e Pro X

The PC Specs are Now
MB: Gigabyte Aorus x670e Pro X
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 7600x3D
GPU: RX 7900 XTX
RAM: G.skill 2x16gb DDR5
SSD: Samsung 980 (I Think)

BIOS was updated to the latest version, Cleared CMOS, run CHKDSK and SFC Commands. What else is there to do before a RMA that could potentially fix this issue?

check the power supply voltages
